# MapBox GL built Xcode project from makefile

Tags: ios, xcode, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I use MapBox GL Native in my project (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native). I was forced to make changes to the source code.
Now I need to build a library for iOS in Xxode from Makefile. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Makefile` included with the git repository.

Just type `make ipackage` from your console.